# PhpExcel Wrap text issue

Tags: php, excel, csv, phpexcel, xlsx

I have issues with converting .xlsx file to .csv. When I try to convert it, csv file appears with Text Wrap activated. Problem is, that I need that csv file to be imported to database, and current format does not let me to do that. I have question, how to disable text wrap when saving csv file, or ignore text wrap when importing file to database?

**Convert:**

```
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php'; // (this should include the autoloader)
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$excel_readers = array(
    'Excel5' , 
    'Excel2003XML' , 
    'Excel2007'
);

$reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$reader->setReadDataOnly(true);

$path = 'temp.xlsx';
$excel = $reader->load($path);

$writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel, 'CSV');
$writer->setDelimiter(',');
$writer->save('temp.csv');
```

**Import to database:**

```
if (file_exists('temp.csv')) {   
            $i=0;
            require "connection.php";
            $handle = fopen("temp.csv", "r");
            $import=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO adherence(
                    dateandtime,
                    lastname,
                    firstname,
                    paidtime,
                    approvedtime,
                    notadhering) VALUES(
                    ?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',', "'")) !== FALSE) {
                if($i>0) {
                $data = str_replace('"', '', $data);
                $myDate =  date("Y/m/d",strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$data[0])));
                $import->bindParam(1, $myDate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $import->bindParam(2, $data[1], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $import->bindParam(3, $data[2], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $import->bindParam(4, $data[3], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $import->bindParam(5, $data[4], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $import->bindParam(6, $data[5], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $import->execute();
                }
                $i++;

            }
            $removal=$db->prepare("delete FROM adherence WHERE approvedtime = '0' OR notadhering IS NULL");
            $removal->execute();

            fclose($handle);
            echo 'IMPORTED' ;
        }
```

Any assistance would be appreciated!

**EDIT**
generated csv file opened with excel:
[image: generated csv file opened with excel]

Same file after disabling wrap text
[image: Same file after disabling wrap text]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that it's "wrap text" that's causing problems, but new line characters in the cells. PHPExcel doesn't provide any means to remove these automatically. The best option would be to iterate over the cells, replacing all occurrences of `"\n"` with a space.

**EDIT**

Something like

```
foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
    foreach ($worksheet->getColumnIterator() as $column) {
        $cellIterator = $column->getCellIterator();
        $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(true);
        foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
            // Convert any rich text cells to plain text
            if ($cell->getDataType() == PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_INLINE) {
                $cell->setValueExplicit($cell->getValue()->getPlainText());
            }
            // Remove any newline characters in string cells
            if ($cell->getDataType() == PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING) {
                $cell->setValue(str_replace("\n", " ", $cell->getValue()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

might help

Comment: None of these in cells, still, how to check it to be sure?

Comment: I can state with absolute certainty that "wrap text" styling is not applied anywhere in the CSV writer; so your issue is nothing to do with "wrap text"

Comment: When I open csv file - i see that every field has wrap text activated, if I deactivate it, and save a file - it is working. But I need it automated

Comment: CSV files do not have "wrap text".... csv files have no styling of any kind, so perhaps you should explain what you actually mean by "wrap text"

Comment: If you want to check the output of a CSV file, open it in a text editor, not in MS Excel..... Excel applies formatting of its own to any CSV file that it loads

Comment: I would suspect that MS Excel is choosing to apply "wrap" for these "cells" because of their length, as your Excel settings are clearly not using the `,` as a separator.... another reason why it isn't a good idea to view a csv file using MS Excel

Comment: Actually your code solved my problem, Now I just have issue applying it. When it work alone in separate file - it works fine - when I add it between scripts in main file- it returns error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function convertXLStoCSV()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95750/discussion-between-justinast-and-mark-baker).